# Can we call modal inside 'required' 'messages' in jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

need help please. I am newbie, I have a task to put a modal dialog if user didn't upload any file inside jquery validation plugin. and I want 'messages' to call a modal, how to do it? is it possible?

Thank you so much for your help.

this is what I've changed:

```
messages:{

'user[image_file_name]': {
                                // required: 'Please browse a file',
                                required: function formSubmit() {
                                    $(#fileUpload).modal("show");
                                },
                                extension: 'File format not supported'
                        },
```

default code is like this:

```
$("#smartform").validate({
                errorClass: "state-error",
                validClass: "state-success",
                errorElement: "em"
                rules: {
                    'user[email]': {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                    },
                    'user[password]': {
                            required: true
                    },
                    'user[password_confirmation]': {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: '#password'
                    },
                    'user[phone_number]': {
                            required: true
                    },
                    'user[full_name]': {
                            required: true
                    },
                    'user[street_address]': {
                            required: true
                    },
                    'user[zip_code]': {
                            required: true
                    },
                    'user[province]': {
                            required: true
                    },
                    'user[image_file_name]':  {
                            required: true,
                            extension:"jpg|png|jpeg"
                    },
                },
                messages:{
                    'user[full_name]': {
                            required: 'Please enter Your full name',
                    },
                    'user[street_address]': {
                            required: 'Please enter Your address ',
                    },
                    'user[phone_number]': {
                            required: 'Please enter Mobile Number',
                    },
                    'user[password]': {
                            required: 'Please enter password',
                    },
                    'user[password_confirmation]': {
                            required: 'Please enter password',
                    },
                    'user[zip_code]': {
                            required: 'Please enter zip code',
                    },
                    'user[province]': {
                            required: 'Please enter province',
                    },
                    'user[image_file_name]': {
                            // required: 'Please browse a file',
                            required: function formSubmit() {
                                $(#fileUpload).modal("show");
                            },
                            extension: 'File format not supported'
                    },
                    'user[email]': {
                            required: 'Enter your email address',
                            email: 'Enter a VALID email address'
                    },
                },
```